# Perl combine multiple file contents to single file

Tags: file, perl

I have multiple log files say file1.log file2.log file3.log etc. I want to combine these files contents and put it into single file called result_file.log

Is there any Perl module which can achieve this?

**Update: Here is my code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Copy;

my @files;

my $dir = "/path/to/directory";

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    # We only want files
    next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

    # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .log
    next unless ($file =~ m/\.log$/);

    print "$file\n";

    push( @files, $file);
}

closedir(DIR);

print Dumper(\@files);

open my $out_file, ">result_file.log" ;
copy($_, $out_file) foreach ( @files );

exit 0;
```

Do you think it is feasible solution?

Comment: What have you tried, what problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Oh, and why do you want to do this with Perl? It sounds to me like a job for the `cat` command.

Comment: @DaveCross I have added script in the question.

Comment: I'm confused -- that last part, using `File::Copy::copy` ... is that from an answer to this question?  If it is, I'd suggest to avoid adding to the question things that get posted in answers -- it's very confusing to the reader.  (Example: That last part is a fine solution of your problem, right as it stands, so if you have that then why the question?)

Comment: @vinodk89 I'm extended the File::Copy answer - see notes about 'readdir' sort vs `glob`, and recommended file closing.

Answer (score 3):

CPAN 'File::Copy' should do the work, you will have to open the output file youself.

```
use File::Copy ;
open my $out, ">result.log" ;
copy($_, $out) foreach ('file1.log', 'file2.log', );
close $out ;
```

**Update 1:**
Based on additional information posted to answer, looks like the ask is to concatenate (in Perl) list of files match a pattern (*.log). Below extends the above solution to include additional logic, using `glob`, avoiding the `readdir` and filtering.

```
use File::Copy ;

open my $out, ">result.log" ;
copy($_, $out) foreach glob('/path/to/dir/*.log' );
close $out ;
```

Important notes:
  * Using glob will SORT the file name alphabetically, while readdir does NOT guarantee any order.
  * The output file 'result.log' match '*.log', should not execute the code in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think it is feasible solution?

I'm afraid not. Your code is the equivalent of typing these commands at your prompt:

```
$ cp file1.log result_file.log
$ cp file2.log result_file.log
$ cp file3.log result_file.log
$ ... etc ...
```

The problem with this is that it copies each file, in turn over the top of the previous one. So you end up with a copy of the final file in the list.

As I said in a comment, this is most easily done using `cay` - no need for Perl at all.

```
$ cat file1.log file2.log file3.log > result_file.log
```

If you really want to do it in Perl, then something like this would work (the first section is rather similar to yours).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @files;

my $dir = "/path/to/directory";

opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {

    # We only want files
    next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

    # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .log
    next unless ($file =~ m/\.log$/);

    print "$file\n";

    push( @files, "$dir/$file");
}

closedir($dh);

print Dumper(\@files);

open my $out_file, '>', 'result_file.log';

foreach my $fn (@files) {
    open my $in_file, '<', $fn or die "$fn: $!";
    print $out_file while <$fn>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DaveCross for the suggestion. ```cat``` looks good option. But these files are dynamic. How can I iterrate through loop inorder to catch these files in cat command.

Comment: @vinodk89: `cat somedir/*.log > result_file.log`